# Bash script cannot find [^.]

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
du -s */ [^.]*/ | sort -n | while read a; do echo $a; done | sed -r 's/^ *([ 0-9]{3})([ 0-9]{3})([ 0-9]{3}) *(.*)\/$/\1 \2 \3 \4/'
```

but for some reason I get this error:

```
du: cannot access `[^.]*/': No such file or directory
```

What am I missing? I don't know what's wrong with my script.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want `.*/` instead of `[^.]*/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't support regexp as file name patterns by default, only [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

Usually, directories that start with `.` are not included in `*/`. If you want to include the save ones, use `.??*/` (excludes `.` and `..`). It's not perfect (misses `.X/`) but is good enough most of the time.

**[EDIT]** You can enable a subset of regexp with `shopt -s extglob` (kudos to [fered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313821/fered) for pointing that out).

See [Bash Extended Globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) for details.

Comment: `bash` (version ≧4) certainly does handle regex globbing: see: [Bash Extended Globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by `[^.]`? If you meant regex excluding dot, then it's equivalent to `*/`.

Also `while read a; do echo $a; done` is more or less a no-op.

EDIT: Based on the comment:

```
(shopt -s dotglob ; eval du -s '*/')
```

Comment: The only thing that while loop will do is to compress sequences of whitespace to a single space (because the `$a` is not quoted)

Comment: I would like to display all folders and their sizes. So I do not want the "." and ".."

Comment: I see, I added the real answer for you.